# USB Flash Drive won't format

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, flash, format

So I have a 16GB Kingston DataTraveler G4 USB Flash Drive and I used Rufus to make it bootable (I used GPT). Now, if I want to format it. It will unmount and leave me with an error saying that it can't find the path specified. I tried using diskpart, disk manager and easeus.

EDIT: I used a software called MiniTool and it seems I still have the Arch Linux installation files on it.

Comment: Please also provide the exact error message

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy Okay. So, for diskpart when I type clean i get: DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified. And for normal format(right click on drive and format) I get Windows was unable to complete the format. And for EaseUs I get: There are some error occurred while formatting FAT partition.